# Rails, how to pass selected value from a dropdown list as same as other values in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, formhelper

I have a form for users to upload pictures with some other informations like name and description. I have two databases tables: one is `albums` and the other is `photos`. In photos table there is a field called `album_id` which connects the photo to the album.

```
<%= form_for(@photo, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <div class='form_text'> Add Photo </div>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='form_text'> Name </div>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='form_text'> Description </div>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= collection_select(:album, :album_id, Album.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true)  %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit 'Upload' %>
  </div>
```

So my problem is that how I can pass the selected value of `album_id` as same as other values. Maybe I am not clear enough, I think the selection is not added into the f object, so when the value passes when click on Upload, name, description and the photo are passed in as one object and the `album_id` is passed as another object. How can make the selection into the f object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
<%= collection_select(:photo, :album_id, Album.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
```

So it would generate a `select` with the id `photo[album_id]`, as your other fields ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I add that value into f object. I saw something on other questions like f.select. but I can make it work with this.

Comment: `f.select(:album_id, Album.all.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id ] } `may be what youre looking for?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now, so it will be passed as same as other fields. And it worked. Thanks a million.